# H2 Insert performances

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am developing a web application with java spring boot and I am using H2 as a database.

I have some performances issues when inserting data. I am correctly doing batch inserts, but what I noticed is that after some time the inserts slow a lot. For example, it takes **100** seconds to insert the first **N** elements, but then it takes **200** seconds to insert the following **N** elements and then **400** seconds for the next **N** elements and so on.

I am struggling to find the problem and fix it. Can someone help?

In order to do the batch I setted the application properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=20
```

I am inserting this entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_son")
public class EntitySon extends EntityFather{

    protected EntitySon (){}

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name ="anotherEntityId")
   private AnotherEntity AnotherEntityId;
}
```

Which inherits from this entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class EntityFather{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 20, sequenceName = "EntitySequence")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ")
    @Column(name ="entityId")
    private Long entityFatherId;

}
```

I am generating a sequence in this way using liquibase:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: createSequence
      author: liquibase-docs
      changes:
        - createSequence:
            sequenceName: EntitySequence
            incrementBy: 20
```

And finally I am doing batch inserts in this way:

```
private void saveEntitySon(List<EntitySon> entitySons){
    long BATCH_SIZE = 20L;
    long batchIter = 0;
    while(true) {
        List<EntitySon> batch = entitySons.stream().skip(batchIter*BATCH_SIZE)
                .limit(BATCH_SIZE*(batchIter+1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (batch.size() < BATCH_SIZE) {
            logger.info("Saving line difference by line difference");
            for (EntitySon entitySon : batch) {
                entitySonRepository.save(entitySon)
            }
            return;
        }else{
                entitySonRepository.saveAll(batch)
        }
        batchIter++;
    }
}
```

I also have to mention that If I delete and recreate the database, I see the same pattern in performances.

Comment: Maybe you could show us some code, otherwise it will be impossible to help you. Where to even start?

Comment: Okay I will provide some code. I would still be interested knowing what's your opinion on what the issue could be.

Comment: Well, your code is steaming more entities each time - if you remove the database insert does it still exhibit the same behaviour? Also not sure why you insert individual items if there are fewer than than batch. Finally, it should automatically batch - I’m not sure why you’re manually creating a list every time; just flush the session every `batch` items.

Comment: Also, son _extending_ father is just ... weird.

Comment: I'm sorry, the code in kinda anonymized so some things don't really make sense, but the key here is the performance. I am focussing on insert performance at the moment, the read are not a problem so far

Comment: OK; so that ended up being a bit long, but to quote Hemmingway "If I Had More Time, I Would Have Written a Shorter Letter".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so you are mixing two things here: **JDBC batch size** and the **JPA** session.

JDBC Batch size will make the underlying JDBC Database Driver batch multiple inserts together, so you save DB round-trips.
JPA is built on top of JDBC and manages state in the "session" or EntityManager. I always like to call persisted entities "managed" entities, to make it clear that there is something that holds and manages state for **each entity** in the current session.

**Caveat:** I'm not sure how memory efficient the stream operation is and I didn't look it up.

You should use a profiler, like VisualVM (which is part of the JDK), or maybe even with the Windows TaskManager, you should be able to see your memory consumption grow.

You are inside one transaction, you persist 100 entities, so your session contains 100 states, then you add more and more. That slows down iteration over the state and garbage collection.

What you want is to **batch on JPA level, too**. Unfortunately, Spring JPA repositories are lacking in this regard. If you look at the code, [saveAll](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/d35ee1a82bf0fdf2de2724a02619eea1cf3c98bd/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L584) does exactly the same thing as your loop (iterate over list and call `save()`).
You need an actual EntityManager here so you can flush statements to the database and then clear the session to delete all state:

```
private void saveEntitySon(List<EntitySon> entitySons){
    long BATCH_SIZE = 20L;

    for (long i = 0L; i < entitySons.size(); i++) {

        if (i > 0 && i % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
            entitySonRepository.flush(); // Could also use EntityManager, doesn't matter
            entityManager.clear(); // This will also detach all entities! So make sure you need to reload them if you want to use them!
        }

        EntitySon entitySon = entitySons.get(i);
        // Using repo so Spring Data JPA events get triggered
        entitySonRepository.save(entitySon);
    }
    
    // Flush out remainder
    entitySonRepository.flush();
    entityManager.clear();
}
```

Like the comment says, be aware that `clear()` will detach all entities. That is a problem if you load/persist an entity before the batch and want to use it afterwards. But usually such a batch job would run by itself anyway.

**EDIT:**
I've assumed you want to do everything in one transaction, so you'd have "all or nothing" persisted. But of course, there is also state management overhead on the Database side and long running transactions can cause conflicts.

It's **always** a good idea to check Vlad Mihalcea's Blog when dealing with JPA and he has an article about batching [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-do-batch-processing-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

The [Hibernate User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch) also has a chapter about batching.

Please realize that Spring Data JPA is a nice, comfortable abstraction for many day-to-day things, but it doesn't allow for precise control and will not be sufficient for many performance critical or more complicated tasks.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I'll try these steps one by one and run my benchmarks and I'll tell you what happens :)